# 'mat-chip-grid' is not a known element

Tags: angular, user-interface, web, angular-material, angular-material2

I am unable to use mat chips module with autocomplete in angular material 15 version. This is all error I am having.

Error: src/app/index/login/login.component.html:4:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-chip-grid' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-chip-grid' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-chip-grid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

4       <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Fruit selection">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/index/login/login.component.ts:11:16
11   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.

Error: src/app/index/login/login.component.html:5:9 - error NG8001: 'mat-chip-row' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-chip-row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-chip-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

5         <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/index/login/login.component.ts:11:16
11   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.

Error: src/app/index/login/login.component.html:12:53 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

12       <input placeholder="New Fruit..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/index/login/login.component.ts:11:16
11   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.

Error: src/app/index/login/login.component.html:13:10 - error TS2740: Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'MatChipList': _elementRef, _changeDetectorRef, _dir, controlType, and 82 more.

13         [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/index/login/login.component.ts:11:16
11   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.

I am trying to use mat chips module as shown in angular material website.

Comment: You have to import [the module](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api)

Comment: I have already imported the same module, it is coming in v15 not with 14 @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Is the `login` component standalone?

Comment: Please add the code of your module. Are you sure you are not importing the legacy chips module?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi there is only one page i created login. I have imported all material module too.

Comment: @JSONDerulo No, I am only using material module as shown in documentation of chips at stackblitz.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, including the code of the module. It's not possible to tell what is going wrong here.